# Video.js: Calling play() method on player instance is not working

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I have a [video.js](https://videojs.com/) player instance I'd like to programmatically start playing by calling the `play()` method on it.

The player's markup…

```
<video-js id   ="some-player-id"
          src  ="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4"
          class="VideoPlayer">
</video-js>
```

[As explained in the documentation](https://videojs.com/guides/player-workflows/#using-playback-information-functions), it should be possible to create a player using the element's `id` and to subsequently call `play()` on it to start playback…

```
// Initialise player instance
const player = videojs.getPlayer("some-player-id");

// When ready, start playback
player.ready(function() {
  player.play()
});
```

However, this is not working for me and I'd like to know why. Pls check the attached snippet for reference.

```js
// Initialise player instance
const player = videojs("some-player-id");

// When ready, start playback
player.ready(function() {
  player.play();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.20.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="VideoPlayer">
  <video-js id   ="some-player-id" 
            src  ="https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" 
            class="VideoPlayer__videoJs">
  </video-js>
</div>

<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.20.1/video.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: no, nothing unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Chrome browser, it might be the culprit here. According to the [policy](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/), the browser will interfere and stop the playback under certain circumstances.

Since the `play()` method returns a promise, we can catch the error by chaining a `catch()` method.

```js
player.play().catch(error => console.log(error));
```

If the browser decides to prevent autoplay, we shall expect the following error.

```
DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.
```

An approach that will always work is to mute the video before playing them.

```js
player.muted(true);
player.play();
```

But what if we start unmuting the videos after the playback starts? The answer is the video will be paused after playing for the muted period.

```js
player.muted(false);

// OR

setTimeout(() => {
  player.muted(false);
}, 3000);
```

AFAIK the bulletproof way to play videos with sound is to provide a fallback by showing a big play button or something equivalent when autoplay fails.